# Change TextSize with a spinner

Tags: java, android, android-spinner, text-size

I managed to change the color of a certain text with a spinner. But now I wanted to change the size of the same text with another spinner. I put the color cases inside a switch function to change the color.

**like that**

```
switch (i) {
                case 0:
                    description.setText(des[i]);
                    preferences.edit().putInt(SELECTED_COLOR, Color.WHITE).apply();
                    break;
                case 1:
                    description.setText(des[i]);
                    preferences.edit().putInt(SELECTED_COLOR, Color.BLUE).apply();
                    break;
```

I wrote all down but I dont know how to call the TextSize inside the case.
I thought it would work like that:

```
 switch (d) {
                case 0:
                    description2.setText(des2[d]);
                    preferences2.edit().putInt(SELECTED_SIZE, ????); <==
            }
        }
```

But I cant use TextSize or something like that.
To change the color I used Color.BLUE/RED/GREEN/... but now I want to change the TextSize... It is as always kind of difficult to explain my problem^^ sry for that.

Comment: You could create your own IntDef (or just plain constants) for text size, similar to how Anroid's color class has constants for `Color`. The constants could refer to an amount in `sp`, and then you set the text size based on that integer value, like `textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, MY_CONST_SIZE);`

Comment: I will try it tomorow :) Thanks for your answer

Comment: I tried it now but couldnt get it working. Do you mean: preferences2.edit().putInt(textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, MY_CONST_SIZE)) ?

Comment: Oh no, I mean to put the `MY_CONST_SIZE` in the preferences, and then set the text size of the `TextView` when you retrieve the value from shared preferences. I'm assuming that's what you're doing with the colors... right? Storing the spinner selection in shared preferences, then retrieving the color in the shared preferences and using that to set the color of a `TextView`?

Comment: Yeah I want to edit the textsize inside another activity. But I think I dont understand your way to do it :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use shared preferences and a switch statement like you do for your colors, you can do something similar to the following:

In your switch statement, similar to how you are handling color, add the text size associated with the selected spinner index to your shared preferences:

```
switch(i) {
    case 0:
        preferences.edit().putInt(SELECTED_SIZE, 16).apply();
        break;
    case 1:
        preferences.edit().putInt(SELECTED_SIZE, 18).apply();
        break;
    // other cases go here...
}
```

Then, in the activity that includes the `TextView` whose text size you want to change (in this example, named `textViewToChange`), retrieve the saved value, and use it to set the text size:

```
SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
int selectedTextSize = preferences.getInt(SELECTED_SIZE, 0);
textViewToChange.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, selectedTextSize);
```